# Testing Statistical Methods

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, statistics, machine-learning

I  write a lot of statistical methods for application.

The problem is I don't know how to test it appropriately.

For example, in unit-test I check whether the sum of all probabilities of distribution converges to 1, however is never 1.

For example, the sum of all probabilities might be 0.9999999 or even 1.0000000005, the actually value if strongly depends on how many different outcomes the distribution have.

maybe I can test like so

```
value should be less that 1.1
value should be more that 0.9
```

but I am not sure that this test is consistent, maybe there is a distribution that due to numeric calculation will output 1.1

How to test it appropriately.

Comment: Can you share the code for an example implementation of a statical method ?

Comment: It sounds like in this particular case you would want to test the difference of the outcome to 1, e.g. assert that it must be with 0.01 of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a related discussion [here](https://hips.seas.harvard.edu/blog/2013/05/20/testing-mcmc-code-part-1-unit-tests/) that you might find interesting.

The short version is that you want to break up your statistical methods into pieces that can be tested deterministically.

Where that's not the case, you probably want to use some epsilon value to compare your expected and actual outputs.  You could also run several iterations of the test and perform a simpler statistical test (a t-test perhaps?) to see if the distribution looks like what you think it should be.